# tomcat application not working via DNS but works via ip

Tags: tomcat

I have four webapps that I have deployed. They work just fine via the following URLs:

- https://192.168.100.254/StingRestInterface
- https://192.168.100.254/StingCommandInterface

However when I type in the URL `https://rest.example.com` or `https://command.exmaple.com` I get a blank white page. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Here is my server.xml
http://pastebin.com/Z2ieRPvZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your host entries, the `unpaWars` are wrong, it should be `unpackWars`.